# Is there a good way to display "clean" text on stdout in CMake

Tags: cmake

Cmake version 2.8.10.2, OS centos 6.3

We're trying to get a "clean" display of text on stdout from within our cmake files. That is, text just as we intend, without a prefix. So far I've tried these variations

This goes to stderr (surprised me):

```
MESSAGE("my text")
```

This goes to stdout but prefixes each line with '-- ':

```
MESSAGE(STATUS "my text")
```

This sort of works, but the side effects are weird and make it undesirable for us:

```
FILE(WRITE /dev/stdout "my text")
```

The above goes to stdout, but breaks if the output from cmake itself is redirected to a file (cmake > file), although it is OK if you you pipe stdout first (cmake | cat > file) but that's hacky and means we have to tell everyone about the workaround which just isn't going to happen.

Comment: execute_process and use it to call a batch/shell script?

Comment: Thought about it, but I'm hoping for a solution where I don't have to worry about platform type. (It's on Linux for now, could be Windows tomorrow.) I suppose I could use cmake itself with something like `cmake -E echo ...`?

Comment: Bingo. That does the trick. If you want to make that an answer I'll check it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could provide the following function:

```
function(CleanMessage)
  execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "${ARGN}")
endfunction()
```

and use it like this:

```
CleanMessage("Clean text")
```

If you want to push the boat out, you could even extend the built-in `message` options to include a `CLEAN` one:

```
function(message MessageType)
  if(${ARGV0} STREQUAL "CLEAN")
    execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "${ARGN}")
  else()
    _message(${MessageType} "${ARGN}")
  endif()
endfunction()
```

and use it like this:

```
message(STATUS "Incidental information")
message(CLEAN "Clean Incidental information")
message(WARNING "CMake Warning, continue processing")
```

This is safe to define in your top-level CMakeLists.txt once.  However, if it's defined in e.g. a utilities file which could be included more than once, it will lead to infinite recursion.  To avoid this, at the start of the utility file in which the function is defined, add:

```
if(OverloadMessageIncluded)
  return()
endif()
set(OverloadMessageIncluded TRUE)
```

This is effectively a CMake version of a header guard.

Comment: For some reason I didn't see this answer when I left my "Bingo" comment above. (Looks like you were answering about the time I left my first comment, just as the light was dawning :-) I really like your suggestion about extending message(), I may do that, thanks!

Comment: Copy and pasted your extended message function but I get a segmentation fault with anything other than CLEAN as the message type. It doesn't like the _message invocation.

Comment: Sorry - I don't have access to CentOS.  I've checked that this works on Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10.  I think the likely reason is the function recursively calling itself.  To avoid this, define the function once in the top-level CMakeLists.txt.  See [this mail](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-March/043320.html) from the CMake mailing list for fuller info.

Comment: Hmm, looked like it was defined only once, but it was in a file that's included in many places, so... Doesn't appear a stable enough hack for production (we can't place it in the top-level CMakeLists.txt file, that's user-supplied from outside our little system of files). Nice trick, potentially, though.

Comment: @William - I added a (more standard) fix for this problem.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this particular file was already guarded - some are, but not this now that I look. Something to add on general principles I think.

Comment: That has some drawback because creates a process to show a simple text which slow downs the entire cmake execution on the Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you prepend your message with a carriage return, you can simply overwrite the dashes.

```
string( ASCII 13 CR ) # carriage return character
message( STATUS "${CR}Hello!" )
```

To make it also work for e.g. empty or single-letter messages, you can explicitly overwrite the dashes with spaces.

```
function( CleanMessage Message )
    string( ASCII 13 CR ) # carriage return character
    set( ClearLine "${CR}  ${CR}" )
    message( STATUS "${ClearLine}${Message}" )
endfunction()
```